# PROC SORT not sorting properly

Tags: sorting, merge, sas, proc

I have large datasets that I am trying to merge. I run PROC SORT on my identifiers and it appears to execute successfully. Then I try to merge and it says the datasets aren't sorted properly. What might be the issue?

Log:

> MPRINT(PHYSICIANASSIGNMENT):   proc sort data=cartemp FORCE SORTSIZE=MAX; 
> MPRINT(PHYSICIANASSIGNMENT):   by phys_id; 
> MPRINT(PHYSICIANASSIGNMENT):   run;
>
> NOTE: There were 344832552 observations read from the data set WORK.CARTEMP. 
> NOTE: SAS threaded sort was used.
> NOTE: The data set WORK.CARTEMP has 344832552 observations and 33 variables.
> NOTE: PROCEDURE SORT used (Total process time):
> real time           47:50.99
> cpu time            5:36.19
>
> MPRINT(PHYSICIANASSIGNMENT):   data cartemp;
> MPRINT(PHYSICIANASSIGNMENT):   merge cartemp (in=clm) carrier_docs (in=specs keep=phys_id spec_overall);
> MPRINT(PHYSICIANASSIGNMENT):   by phys_id;
> MPRINT(PHYSICIANASSIGNMENT):   if clm;
> MPRINT(PHYSICIANASSIGNMENT):   drop phys_id preferred_id;
> MPRINT(PHYSICIANASSIGNMENT):   run;
>
> ERROR: BY variables are not properly sorted on data set WORK.CARTEMP.
> clm=1 specs=1 preferred_id=112893791 bene_id=quwdhauiASHHHa phys_id=D23879_129389812938 spec_overall=0 FIRST.phys_id=0 LAST.phys_id=0 *ERROR*=1 *N*=45258476 
> NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.

Whether I use the "FORCE" option in PROC SORT doesn't change anything.

Apologies if this is obvious; I'm fairly new to SAS.

Comment: This is not normal.  Open a ticket with SAS support. You are paying for their support so use it.

Comment: Try changing the code so that you are not overwriting your original datasets.

Comment: 50 minutes to sort to WORK so you can do a MERGE lookup is not a good use of all that computing power.  You should be able to lookup PREFERRED_ID (indexed on phys_ID) and add to CARTEMP without sorting and do some other work in the same step.  344832552 obs is a lot of data for anyone, new to SAS or not.

Comment: I agree with Tom that this problem should be raised to SAS support. Nevertheless, as mentioned by data_null_, you can avoid sorting explicitly by creating an index on `phys_ID` or using hash keys to merge via a data step. Although using indices is more common than hash keys (please check the SAS documentation on creating indices and using them to merge datasets), you can take a look at the following article for more info on hash keys: https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings20/4415-2020.pdf

Comment: Assuming this is resolved, but you could check if carrier_docs is sorted. The SAS error may be wrong.